# How to add custom group in list setting page?

Tags: 2010, 2013, custom-actions

I want to add one custom action in my custom group. I have done following for that

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomActionGroup
               Id="LibrarySettings.MyGroup"
               Title ="My Group"
               Sequence="1000" 
               Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.ListEdit">
  </CustomActionGroup>
  <CustomAction Id="Custom.Configuration.ListCustomSettings"
               GroupId="LibrarySettings.MyGroup"
               Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.ListEdit"
               RequireSiteAdministrator="FALSE"
               Sequence="100"
               Title="Library Admins">
    <UrlAction Url="_layouts/15/LibrarySettings.aspx?List={ListId}" />
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

But custom group is not created in list settings

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that we cannot create custom action group in list settings page as those section are hardcoded in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\listedit.aspx.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/153d72db-b966-4dea-a1c3-f6b621219233/how-to-add-custom-action-group-in-list-settings-page?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious#153d72db-b966-4dea-a1c3-f6b621219233